# How can the users of my web app generate private SSH keys without the command line?

Tags: authentication, encryption, ssh, web-applications

I understand setting up SSH from the command line of your local computer.
But app users shouldn't be using the command line, obviously.

How can a private SSH key be generated for each user, enabling passwordless connection to the remote server without using the command line?

SSH is a popular, more secure alternative to typical login methods, right? How is it usually done from the users point of view?

Comment: As a user, I wouldn't trust an **any** external website to generate my own encryption keys. As it is, I suppose you could use client-side JavaScript (with modern JS's built-in support for [crypto](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Crypto) primitives and client-side crypto-secure RNG) and use that with JS's binary file API to make a 100%-client side SSH key-generation page.

Comment: I'm not aware of web applications that involve the app user logging in to the remote computer with SSH, so I'm a little confused.

Comment: You may just generate a keypair of any supported algorithm (rsa, ecdsa,..) still your server has to trust the individual certificates and assign them to individual users upfront. The security of ssh pubkey is in the ownership of the private key. The same way you may just generate users' passwords and then you have the same issue how the server would validate it.